# MySQL / PHP - Find available time slots

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

There have been a few questions asked on similar topics but I cannot find a solution to this specific problem and would be thankful for your input.

I am working on a booking engine where users can book certain services online. I am stuck on finding and displaying available time slots within a specific day (or week). I know the length of the needed time slot (eg. 1 hour) and the business hours in which time slots are bookable (eg. 09:00h - 18:00h). Additionally I have a MySQL table that stores the already existing appointments. The columns relevant to my questions look like this:

```
id  start (datetime)        end (datetime)
1   '2012-11-16 13:00:00'   '2012-11-16 14:30:00'
2   '2012-11-16 15:00:00'   '2012-11-16 16:00:00'
3   '2012-11-17 12:00:00'   '2012-11-16 15:45:00'
4   '2012-11-17 13:00:00'   '2012-11-16 16:15:00'
...
```

Now given the information mentioned above, I am unable to find a good solution (in MySQL or PHP) for retrieving a list of available time slots. There is one more condition: Time slots can only start in quarterly steps. Ie. for the example data above on the 16th available one hour time slots would be:
09:00, 09:15, 09:30, 09:45, 10:00, ..., 12:00, 16:00, 16:15, ..., 17:00.

Please note that even though there may be overlapping times (as in sample data) an available time slot cannot overlap.

What would you think is the best way to approach this?

Comment: What are the conditions of the overlap? Are they for a booking of services with one person, or can more than one appointment happen simultaneously?

Comment: It is for a booking of one person. A regular user would only be able to book a time slot that is 100% free ie. no overlap. Admins have a different/mores sophisticated calendar that allows overlaps (as they may know that they can handle an overlap in certain situations). For the question above I guess the only important point is that there may be overlapping slots in the database table in which the system should try and find availability.

Answer (score 8):

```sql
SELECT a.end AS free_after
FROM bookings a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM bookings b
  WHERE b.start BETWEEN a.end AND a.end + INTERVAL your_duration HOURS
)
AND a.end BETWEEN start_of_search_window AND end_of_search_window;
```

you just need to supply values for `your_duration` (integer), `start_of_search_window` (date time) and `end_of_search_window` (date time).

And if you want bells and whistles....

```sql
SELECT free_from, free_until
FROM (
  SELECT a.end AS free_from,
  (SELECT MIN(c.start)
   FROM bookings c
   WHERE c.start > a.end) as free_until
  FROM bookings a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM bookings b
    WHERE b.start BETWEEN a.end AND a.end + INTERVAL your_duration HOUR
  )
  AND a.end BETWEEN start_of_search_window AND end_of_search_window
)
ORDER BY free_until-free_from
LIMIT 0,3;
```

Will give you the three shortest available slots (i.e. nearest the target size) within the window.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for! Do you think it would also be possible to get the result as all available slots. In the example above one result row is: 2012-11-16 16:00:00 - 2012-11-17 12:00:00.  Instead of this I'd prefer many rows containing the time slots such as: 2012-11-16 16:00:00 - 2012-11-16 17:00:00 and 2012-11-16 17:00:00 - 2012-11-16 18:00:00 and so on... Or would you split up the entire free time into slots later using PHP?

Comment: One more thing, I have played around with your solution and have found one tricky problem I cannot solve by myself. If I use your statement with start_of_search_window 2012-11-16 00:00:00 and end_of_search_window 2012-11-18 00:00:00 it misses the free block between 2012-11-16 00:00:00 and 2012-11-16 13:00:00. Ie. it only starts with the free_from after the first appointment it finds. Can you point me to the right direction of how to fix this bug..?

Comment: Conceptually it's trivial - just substitute the 'bookings a' table with a vierw that includes a dummy appointment ending at the start of your window - but the SQL is rather more complex.

Comment: May be trivial but i has not been able to set up a floor and ceiling for this query.