# find space in a mysql database calendar for new appointment

Tags: php, mysql

Completely lost here. I have a mysql database with an appointment table. The important for this is that is has a start_date and end_date

Suppose I need to find the next available 30 minute slot. Need to stat Mon-Fri and 7am to 7 pm

Basically I need a way to automatically do this process. What would my sql query look like?

select * from calendar where end_date < now and ???? lost

Comment: Instead of dealing with dates, you should look at another approach to the solution. From 7 AM to 7 PM you have 12 hours, and with 30 minute time slots -- 24 time slots. If you use some kind of bit-mask to represent what slots are available or not, you could simplify the query and the problem.

Comment: I would fetch all future appointments and search for the next slot in a php loop. I've tried to do that in [SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24e070/1) and stopped because of growing complexity. While it's still possible - it's almost unmaintainable.

Comment: A proper example would help to clarify the problem

Comment: Landen - Yes I believe you are right. I need to think about this outside of SQL in PHP. Still havent grasped the idea 100% but I certainly couldnt fiqure it out in SQL. Thank you everyone

Comment: Might want to check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414795/mysql-php-find-available-time-slots

Comment: Razvan that is a great link, thanks for finding that one! Sure appreciate everyone's suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Considering I'm not fluent in SQL but I just tried to solve problem. Is something like this may solve the problem ?

```
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date) as time_diff FROM calendar WHERE  start_date > NOW() AND (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date)) / 60) > 30;
```

If you add `ORDER BY start_date` and `LIMIT 1` you would get the first match.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't worried of the "empty" slots in the appointment table, you can set up a procedure that periodically pre-allocate the slots up to the "booking horizon" (eg. end of next month) and deletes the past "empty" slots.

```
create table `appointment` (
    `slot`   varchar (90),
    `remarks` varchar (180)
); 
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 08:00','');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 09:00','');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 10:00','');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 11:00','Tennis with Mark');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 12:00','Lunch at home');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 13:00','Programming');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 14:00','');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 15:00','');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 16:00','');
insert into `appointment` (`slot`, `remarks`) values('2016-03-01 17:00','');
...
...
delete from `appointment` where slot < '2016-02-01' and remarks='';
```

The query to find the first appointment in the example is simple:

```
select * from `appointment` where `slot` > '2016-03-01' and `remarks` = ''
```

But you can create more complex search patterns:

```
select * from `appointment` 
where left(`slot`,10) between '2016-03-01'  and '2016-03-01'
and right(`slot`,5) between '15:00' and '17:00'
and `remarks` = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a technical answer, just because the issue is not technical, but logical. I got myself in the same situation some time ago, and I quickly realised that searching through a whole appointments table is simply to extreme, due to the constantly increasing size of the table, and the resourses it needs.
Plus, I had to deal with various time intervals, for example there are 10 minutes appointments, 5 minutes appointments and 15 minutes appointments.

Therefor I approached this logicaly and I came to the folowing solution:

- I used 5 minutes intervals as a measurment unit
- I divided the hourly interval of the specified doctor to 5 minutes and memorized that result (for example in one day there were 40 intervals)
- every time an appointment is made or canceled, I would check the time intervals remaining for that day. For example when an appointment is created, I add the time intervals required for that appointment to the rest of the intervals already occupied for that day, and I extract the time when the appointment is canceled.
- whenever a day gets filled completely, or the intervals remaining are to few to allow an appointment, I mark that day as full
- when I need to know the firs available appointment, I simply check for the first day that is not full

In that manner, the job is the same for the database, because it has the same workload every time.